# Wrong folder permission

Tags: magento-1.9, file-permissions

I know this has been asked a million times, but I can't find the right answer.

I have a Magento 1.9 on a shared server. Images keeps failing to show. I can change the folder permissions through FileZilla and the images shows up, but in the next product it is wrong again.
I can see that Magento is creating new folders with the permiision 750 and images with 640.

Can I change it somewhere so the permissions is right?

Answer (score 2):

the preferred permission to be given to a folder and file structure in Magento should be

> 755 to all folders
>   644 to all files

don't forget to use recursively to sub directories and files in them.

```
find /var/www/directory/folder/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +
find /var/www/directory/folder/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +
```

Comment: That works, but when I go to the next product and Magento is creating a new folder inside the cache folder. The permission is wrong and the image is not shown.
There must be somewhere I can tell Magento what the permission should be by default.

Comment: you need to use sudo, before running these commands. and it will solve the purpose. But watch out to the use of sudo everytime.

Comment: sudo find /var/www/directory/folder/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +

Comment: Won't this only work for created folders and files? When Magento creates a new subfolder inside the cache folder, files in that folder is not working. It is the permission on new folders that is wrong.

Comment: that's why i have mentioned to use sudo, so it will do is that, whenever a new folder was created inside existing, it will transfer the same permission to new one, because 1. we are using sudo 2. we are using -R recursively.

Comment: Are there any solutions when I do not have SSH access to the shared server.
Can I set the file permission in the code that generate the cached images?

Comment: you can try by this http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Answer (score 0):

Do it via `ssh`, command to run: `chmod 755 -R /var/www/yourMagentoProject/media`

`-R` for a **recursive.**

If you just want products images:  `chmod 755 -R /var/www/yourMagentoProject/media/catalog`

Comment: Will that also work for new folders created by Magento?